# Can i create a class that all my View Controllers can access

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating app with multiple view controllers and each View Controllers contains text Fields for getting user input. So, i want to customize the textFields for each view controller seperately like border radius , border color etc. I want the properties of textFields in one view controller to be different from another view controller.

Is it possible to create a class in a (swift File) with methods for customization so that each view controller can make use of those methods and i can modify the values in the method ? and if so How ?

I was able to customize the textFields in one view controller with this:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    convenience init(netHex:Int) {
        self.init(red:(netHex >> 16) & 0xff, green:(netHex >> 8) & 0xff, blue:netHex & 0xff)
    }
}

extension UITextField{
    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let greenish = UIColor.init(netHex: 0x85b51)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = greenish.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true    
    }
}
```

when i copied the code to another view controller, so i could modify . i was getting errors Invalid

redeclaration of 'init(netHex:)', Invalid redeclaration of 'init(red:green:blue:)'

I am new to ios app development and i have been doing a lot of research trying to understand whats going on. i would appreciate any help and any pointers . Thanks

Comment: I think the pointthat you are missing is that you extend the Class, not the instance of the class.  So if you create an extension to the class it is available to all instances of that class wherever they are used.  So there is no need to copy the extension between view controllers.  Breaking the extensions out into their own file will help reinforce this way of thinking.

Comment: Why don't you just use `UInt8` for you're 0..255 `init` method instead of all those `assert`s?

Comment: Your question is really about the `Invalid redeclaration` errors you are getting. Check your code (and API docs) to see if your init methods don't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to add all extensions in separates files depend on it and in function parameters add value which you want to change (for example border width or color) if you need it

In general that's enough to create one extension and its will be available in all project

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Comment: Thank you all . It's best to place my extensions in separate files. I'm going to look into how to create functions within the extensions , so that each view controller will  be able to modify the values i.e(border width, color) . Any pointers will be appreciated . Thanks again every one !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy extensions like this, the should be valid in all of your app components. So just call the methods you want to use in your second view controller. Often it might make sense to put extensions to UIKit components or other framework components in separate files rather than in your view controller swift file so that they are easier to find. For instance you could have a file name "UIColor-extensions.swift" and put all extnesions to UIColor in it.

Comment: Thanks that what i'm going to do !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your custom views that van be used across the whole app, I would suggest going with @ibdesignable and @ibinspectable.